# Stoping our Test SQL server generate errors on ours production Sharepoint Server

Tags: 2010, sql-server

We have a SharePoint 2010 production server (A) linked to a SQL server production server (B).

We also have a SharePoint 2010 test server (X) linked to a SQL server Test server (Y).

When we stop the SQL service on the SQL server Test server (Y), we are getting errors on the SharePoint 2010 production server (A).

Exemple, if I go ***Central Administration -> Timer Job Status***, we get an error page and the event viewer is filler with error like :

```
Unknown SQL Exception 2 occurred. 
Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection 
to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance 
name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

We also got some errors with the search at some point but those error don't appear every time.

We verified **Central Administration -> Manage Databases Upgrade Status** and every database is on the SQL server production server (B) and nothing is set in the "Failover Database Server" of the WSS_Content and SharePoint_AdminContent database.

We tried many tings like "Clearing the SharePoint Configuration Cache" and so on, but no luck yet.

What are we missing?

### Update :

We just noticed that there is a copy of the production Configuration Database `SharePoint_Config` on both the **B and Y server**.

- In SQL server Management studio's Activity monitor on the **B server**, we notice that the **A server** in connected to all database except the `SharePoint_Config` database.
- In SQL server Management studio's Activity monitor on the **Y server**,  we notice that the **X server** in connected to all database plus the **A server** connection to the `SharePoint_Config` database.

Meanwhile, everything indicate it should connect on the B server.
Example, if we go in **Central Administration : Servers in Farm*** on the A server.

```
Configuration database version: 14.0.7149.5000 
Configuration database server: (Name of server B) 
Configuration database name: SharePoint_Config
```

Same thing in **Central Administration : Manage Databases Upgrade Status**, we see the `SharePoint_Config` database, but it say (Name of server B) for the SQL Instance.

Comment: Did you try rebooting test sql db server?

Comment: We did the following : stopped the SQL service on Y, Restart B, Restart A, (At this point both Sharepoint root site and administration site where giving the error "Cannot connect to configuration database"), restart B again (same  "Cannot connect to configuration database" error), Restart Y. (Sharepoint root site and administration site are back online) but we still got the errors if we stop the test sql db server.

Comment: From review database status page from central admin, which db server is pointed on which server? Also are u using any alias? On test sql server check if the any production database over their.

Comment: in "Central Administration : Manage Databases Upgrade Status" All database of the server A point on server B and All database of the server X point on server Y. I checked everywhere and we are not using any alias.

Comment: does both server having the same name for SharePoint config db? by chance could you please check how many Config db you have on the server y?

Comment: Yes, that the problem, on the **Y** server, there is the "SharePoint_Config" database which is the **A** server's config bd and the "WSS_Config" database which is the **X** server's config bd. So, somehow, the "SharePoint_Config" is on both the **B** and **Y** server, But the **A** server decided to take the one on the **Y** server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved ours problems with the ***SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard***.

First, we took a backup of the `SharePoint_Config` database from Server **Y** and restored it on server **B** to make sure we keep the same settings.

Then we executed the ***SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard***. at the ***Modify server farm Settings*** page, we selected the option **Disconnect from this server farm** and completed the wizard.

We executed the ***SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard*** telling it to connect to an existing server farm. We setted it to use the `SharePoint_Config` database from Server **B** and managed to find the original passphrase we used at the first install.

We had to start some service manually, but everything is fine now.